# Why is SQL Timestamp not UTC?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I select the current date from SQL like this:

```php
foreach ($dbh->query('SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as `now`;') as $row) {
  echo $row['now'];
}
```

and the output is this: `2015-01-24 12:46:45`. This is the time on my computer, which is in `GMT-0500 (EST)`.  However, I thought that SQL timestamps were supposed to be in `UTC` always?  Why is this timestamp not in UTC?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx

Comment: @fortune - #1305 - FUNCTION users.GETUTCDATE does not exist

Comment: what is your database server sql server or mysql?

Comment: Internally, it is stored in UTC.  It is converted to printable form in the local timezone in most retrieval contexts.  If you don't like that, specify the timezone you want to see with [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule that says it has to be in UTC, on the contrary see the documentation (emphasis mine):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp

> Returns the current time as a value in 'HH:MM:SS' or HHMMSS.uuuuuu
>   format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or
>   numeric context. **The value is expressed in the current time zone.**

There is a `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` function to get the timestamp in UTC, also you can use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function (but that will give you a different data type).

Comment: But if I am in, say, EST, and I add an entry, then someone in PST adds one at the exact same time, won't the timestamps be different?

Comment: @VinnieCaprarola Yes, that's true. That's why there are functions such as `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` as well :)

Comment: OK- the UTC_TIMESTAMP() function returns what I wanted - thank you!